# Google is indexing my website pages with hash bang fragment parameters not used in my web application

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

In the Google Search Console I have a lot of "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" (34k for 46k valid pages) with these weird fragment identifier parameters:

`https://example.com/somepage#!&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiC2ajdlfTKAhUIUBQKHUbKAb4QwW4INDAP&usg=AFQjCNFmuH2B1N0_0ykScXJwPz1xmEi1mA`

The parameters `sa`, `ved` and `usg` seem to be used by google for its tracking, I am not using this kind of query string parameters at all in my application.

These URL have the right "canonical URL declared by user" (`https://example.com/somepage` for this example) but I'd like to know where this can come from, is it due to Google Analytics or something like this? Can I avoid this?

Comment: "I am not using this kind of query string parameters" - these aren't part of the "query string" (although they would have been part of the referring query string in yesteryears Google), they form part of the _fragment identifier_ in this instance - which can only be processed by client-side JavaScript. The format `#!` (hash bang) is typical of legacy AJAX applications (a Google specification, now deprecated).

Comment: Oh right, I didn't know about the hash-bang thing. If I understand correctly it was used to allow the crawler to see the pages with content loaded via AJAX, ok. Thank you for your lights ;)
The fact is that I do not use any hashbang in my application (which is an Angular app rendered by Angular Universal), do you have any clue on where these links can come from?

Comment: The URLs look a little different, but the answer is the same as for [Why are bots repeatedly crawling pages of my site that I never created?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126985/why-are-bots-repeatedly-crawling-pages-of-my-site-that-i-never-created).